# RequestContext in composite control

Tags: asp.net, routes

I'm trying to access the route data within a composite control to change the directory lookup for images based on the section the user is browsing to.

e.g: http://www.mysite.com/photos/palmtrees

In this cause, {palmtrees} = {id} and I'd like to access this within a composite control.

I've read up about similar requirements but cannot seem to the get RequestContext to return anything but null?

```
// this.Context = HttpContext.Current;

HttpContextBase htb = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);
RequestContext rc = new RequestContext(htb, RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(htb));

// rc -> is always NULL?
```

Is there an easier way to get the RouteData within my control?

Answer (score 0):

Jumping between routes was outside of the route context, meaning that RouteData was never available.

Ensured that when a user clicks on a button to take them to /photo/{id} the context of the route was activated.

Not using MVC, this is a Web Form project.